# A person that shows officials where to go

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the name of a person that guides officials during visits or other public appearances and basically acts only to show them where to go next?

For example, the person I'm talking about is leftmost in this gif:

[image: President-elect Donald Trump walking down the stairs]

Example sentence:

> President-elect Donald Trump was left hanging by a _______ that was pointing him in the opposite direction.

Comment: Looks like a trump handler. Sometimes they take several trumps for a walk, on leashes. This one is off-leash, though - *WAAAAAY* off-leash.

Comment: @Drew I like it. Evidently the "Trump Handler" [sic] is otherwise known as an usher or a majordomo, the head honcho of the ushers.

Comment: The President-elect seems to have lost his bearings in this clip. He's all at sea. I hope he manages to steer himself and the great Ship-of-State on a more even keel come his inauguration. Hail to the Chief, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This person is often called a **protocol specialist**, **protocol officer**, or **protocol handler**.  In the US, many of them work for the State Department under the [Chief of Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_of_Protocol).

Comment: Yeah, probably *protocol officer*, for the person actually telling people where to go.  (Makes one want to be Trump's protocol officer for a few minutes, what?)

Comment: @JohnFeltz Yes, evidently the White House had assigned a mere underling of a protocol officer, one that appears to be a humble usher whom the President-elect fails to glad-hand with any degree of presidential decorum that might have been expected.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the person in the video is a protocol officer. See http://work.chron.com/duties-protocol-officers-21132.html and https://careers.state.gov/ff/position-descriptions/all-pds/u/protocol-officer. He seems more like a simple guide. It's possible he's a Secret Service agent.